# Lotus Notes Emails going to Outlook Group

Tags: outlook, lotus-notes, exchange-server

I am trying to send email to a Lotus Notes group from a Lotus Notes application, But email is sent to Outlook group with same name. Is there any way that email be sent to LN group not to exchange group.

Here LN is not used for mailing anymore. It is done by Exchange.

Comment: More info needed.  Is this an application running on a Notes client or a browser? Or is it agent code running on the Domino server? Or is it a stand-alone application written in Java, C#, etc.?  Secondly, what happens if a Notes client user manually sends an email message to the group name?  Does it go to the Domino group or to the Exchange group?  (I know you said that you don't use Notes for email any more, but this is for troubleshooting and it is the most important test you could possibly do to understand the nature of the problem.)

Comment: it is a client based application. its the code behind an action which sends that email. I checked sending email manually and it is going to exchange address.

Comment: Try sending to "YourGroupName@YourDominoDomainName".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  Making a few assumptions about your setup it sounds like at one of our clients.  Domino is used for apps but exchange for email, with domino routing mail via exchange.
The the domain is something like xyz.com  then sending a mail to "MyGroup" will go to MyGroup.xyz.com and via exchange.
To send just to domino you need to use the Local primary Internet domain which is configured under the Messaging\Domains section in server config on Conversions tab.  In our case it's domino.xyz.com   so sending a mail to mygroup@domino.xyz.com would go to domino and not routed to exchange

Answer (score 0):

Set your Notes group's type as 'Access Control List' only, so it won't be considered a mailable name.